# By the end of the month, should I drop unused event cards?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

I've just finished January game. The instruction for end game for either case says:

> Discard all City cards. These all reset for the start of the next game. Do not put any Legacy cards back in the Legacy deck, even if playing the same month. Just continue where you left off in the Legacy deck.

Source: https://www.ultraboardgames.com/pandemic/legacy-season-1.php

This would imply that in February I start the game with the unused event cards at hand. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

From the same rules it appears that the event cards are chosen before each game so you will be using them again.

> Funding
> At the beginning of each game, you will add Funded Event cards
> (of the group's choice) to the Player Deck equal to your Funding
> Level. Your Funding Level is 4 at the beginning of the first game in
> January but will go up and down from game to game. The minimum funding
> is 0 and the maximum is 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is a strange way of phrasing the rules but you don’t keep any cards in your hand. (I think that legacy games have this unique problem of explaining what is permanent from game to game.)

The only things that carry over from one game to the next are:

- things written down (in the campaign log, on characters),
- stickers (on cards, the board, characters, and in the rules),
- things that were destroyed stay destroyed,
- dossiers doors and boxes that were opened stay open,
- the state of the Legacy Deck.

Essentially, you don’t undo what can’t be undone and you don’t reset the Legacy Deck. Everything else is set up again as described in the setup instructions. This includes the deck of player cards including choosing Funded Events (provided you still have Funding).